# Unable to put a ByteBuffer inside another greater ByteBuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I have the following piece of code:

```
byte[] payloadArray = getPayload();
int size = (HEADER_SIZE+payloadArray.length);
ByteBuffer cmdBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(HEADER_SIZE+payloadArray.length);

//create command
ByteBuffer lengthBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
lengthBuf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
lengthBuf.putChar((char)(size-2));

cmdBuffer.put(lengthBuf);

cmdBuffer.put(getFlag());
```

After the execution of the last command the first two bytes of `cmdBuffer` should show the value from `getFlag()` and `lengthBuf`. Though, this is not visible inside `cmdBuffer`.

I am not sure what is the issue here. Could someone please help?

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? Do you get an exception? Or the code does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the reason is that there are no remaining bytes in `lengthBuf`.

From the JavaDoc on `putChar(char)`:

> Writes two bytes containing the given char value, in the current byte order, into this buffer at the current position, and then increments the position by two.

From the JavaDoc on `put(ByteBuffe)`:

> ...
>   Otherwise, this method copies n = src.remaining() bytes from the given buffer into this buffer, starting at each buffer's current position. The positions of both buffers are then incremented by n.

So the put operation reads from the current position of `lengthBuf` which is the end and there are no bytes left.

Try `lengthBuf.reset()` after `putChar(...)` which should reset the position only. Please note that depending on the buffer implementation `reset()` might not be supported, but `ByteBuffer.allocate()` creates a `HeapByteBuffer` which supports that operation.

**Edit:**

Oleg Estekhin noted that you'd better use `lengthBuf.flip()` instead of `lengthBuf.reset()`.

From the JavaDoc:

> After a sequence of channel-read or put operations, invoke this method to prepare for a sequence of channel-write or relative get operations.

Comment: Your explanation is right but you forget to suggest `lengthBuf .flip()` befure putting it into the destination buffer to get the desired behavior.